Getting MethodError: no method matching *(::Vector{Float64}, ::Vector{Float64}) on julia FractionalDiffEq
used the FractionalDiffEq package correctly below as said in the documentation text
but kept on getting the error above.
P.S: I am running the code in google colabs
using FractionalDiffEq

function Lorenz(du, u, t)
    du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1]);
    du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3])-u[2];
    du[3] = (u[1]*u[2])-(2.66667*u[3]);
end
LE = FOLyapunov(Lorenz, 0.98, 0, 0.02, 300, [0.1; 0.1; 0.1], 0.005, 1000)

Tried using the . with my operators but kept getting the same error
Edits
Got this now as the lyapunov exponents with varying alpha for Fractional order Lorenz differential equation. Is it correct ?


In FractionalDiffEq version 0.3.5, FOLyapunov is apparently broken and commented out.

So do u have any other means or way I can get an algo to find the lyapunov exponents of Fractional order Lorenz differential equation, I'll prefer python if u have please

In FractionalDiffEq version 0.3.1, the test case shows FOLLyapunov called as follows:
(LE, tspan)=FOLyapunov(RF, 0.999, 0, 0.02, 300, [0.1; 0.1; 0.1], 0.005, 1000)

The second argument is a single number, and the return value is a tuple.  (Apparently the code has not caught up with the documentation or vice versa.)
